# Terminal command "open" to launch an app in a specific monitor screen

Tags: terminal, display

I am using two monitor screens and I would like to use the open command in the terminal to launch an app on a specific monitor.

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Why terminal? If I tried to do something like this, I think I would use [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/). That said, I use [Moom](https://manytricks.com/moom/) for window management. Pretty effortless to first open an application with Alfred or by any other method and then press a custom shortcut defined in Moom to move it to another screen if needed and then another shortcut to resize to a portion of the screen if needed. Is there any reason why this workflow wouldn't do it for you?

Comment: Because I use terminal to open vim, ssh, to compile code, and several other stuff...    Then it would be nice to use directly the terminal to distribute these windows in two screens. As you I use Alfred also and Spectacle instead of Moom.

Comment: I have once tried to do something similar with Alfred and the thing I couldn't figure out was how to reliably wait for an application to open. It would've also been a lot of work to make it flexible, like _"open `app-name` `2` `right`"_... I just ended up deciding that it wasn't worth it. I was going to make a typo every time using it anyways and then wish I'd not spent all that time making it. Easier to just chain a bunch of shortcuts manually. — I don't know if this interests you, but in Moom you can save window layouts, which makes arranging multiple windows a bit easier.

Comment: Ok thank you very much in any case! In any case, as you suggest, I'll definitely try Moom

Answer (score 2):

I'm using an eGPU with a dummy plug/headless adapter, and for the eGPU to work, the dummy display must be set to primary.  I have two active displays - my MBP internal display, and my Cinema Display.  The eGPU is working.

However, all of my applications - including system preferences and finder windows open on my dummy display.

I purchased Moom, and sent a ticket with my issue, but he said it's a visual app, and if I can't see the window, I can't use Moom with it.  So Moom was a waste of $10.

I downloaded Alfred, but when I double-click the DMG file, it goes over to the dummy display as well.

Any idea of how I might open or move windows to either display 2 or 3?

So far I am not finding any solution.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! This does not provide an answer to the question. If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: I’m going to keep this up for two reasons. 1. The question has answers in the comments. This explains how those answers don’t work. Even an answer saying x and y don’t work is helpful.